# Is it possible to make a transaction that includes insertions in two different databases (MongoDB and MySQL) using Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mongodb, spring-aop

Here's my senario :

I have a spring intergation flow, in which I do insertions on MongoDB and MySQL databases : I'm storing data into Mongo, doing some treatements then inserting data into MySQL using Spring Data (insertions of both databeses are not in same class)

All repos, services, aop transactions and everything is implemented, what I need is a way to start a transaction before storing data into Mongo and end it after finishing the mysql insertions, so that if any problem occured, both MySQL and Mongo insertions will Rollback.

Hope I was clear explaining my essue! Thanks in advance

Comment: a transaction is a internal list of changes to a database so, no you can't have 1 transaction across 2 databases. you would need 1 transaction per database which if successful you can commit in sequence or roll back seperately

Comment: Thank you @MikeT 
So I'll need a way to memorise stored data from mongo then delete them in case of problem when inserting into MySQL DB

Comment: it depends if the mongo driver you are using supports transactions

Comment: This might get a bit complicated due to the fact that MongoDB doesn't have transactions.

Comment: @Philipp it has Two Phase Commits which can simulate the commit rollback behaviour see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: Humm! What do you think of getting  _id of storing data?

Comment: All thanks to you @MikeT I figured out many things by invoking this issue!

Comment: Thank you @Philipp sharing your ideas

Answer (score 1):

a transaction is a internal list of changes to a database so, no you can't have 1 transaction across 2 databases.

you would need 1 transaction per database which if successful you can commit in sequence or roll back separately

sudo:

```
Create MySQL tansaction
Change MySQL 
if Successful
    Create Mongo Transaction
    change Mongo 
    if Successful
       Commit Mongo changes
       Commit MySQL changes
    else 
       rollback Mongo changes
       rollback MySQL changes
else
    rollback MySQL changes
```